# Javascript closures with let variable

Tags: javascript, closures

Why does javascript closure work differently in these examples?

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i)
  }, 1000);
}
// Output: 0, 1, 2
```

```
let i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i)
  }, 1000);
}
// Output: 3, 3, 3
```

Comment: this one right here is probably the most asked javascript interview question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code example, you have **three** different `i` variables and in each iteration of the loop, callback function of `setTimeout` closes over a *different* copy of `i` variable.

In the second code example, there is only **one** `i` variable and in each iteration of the loop, callback function of `setTimeout` closes over the *same* `i` variable.

There is only one `i` variable in the second code example because you have declared it outside the loop; as a result, each iteration of the loop sees the *same* variable `i`.

In order to get the same output in the second code example, change it as shown below:

```js
let i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

  let j = i; // save a copy of the current value of 'i'
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(j);  // closure over a different 'j' variable in each iteration
  }, 1000);
}
```